# Method of payment without Magento Connect

Tags: payment-methods, magento-connect

I hope you can help me.
I have a group of shops where I'd like install the payment method Western Union, but I cannot use Magento Connect. 
That way I could get the package files Western Union without using this tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somehow unclear. But in case I understood correctly and you want to get some extension that is on magento connect and you don't want to use the magento connect module that's built in Magento, you can use this:  http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php.
it will give you a zip with the files of the extension you need.

Comment: Just wanted to add that using freegento to download and review any extension available via Magento Connect is a good policy. I would never recommend installing any extension without fully reviewing the code and file structure. From a security perspective it is critical to know how data is being handled and from a trouble shooting / customization perspective it will save time as well as it is easier to walk through the limited files of an extension compared to locating and reviewing files once placed into a store.

Comment: Thank you!! I've solved my problem. I can't use Magento Connect because somebody made a bad installation.